# How do I create a systemd service that doesn't start on reboot?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, systemctl

I want to create a systemd service which I can start manually by using systemctl start  but I don't want it to run automatically when the system reboots. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

When you configure the systemd service, to make it start on boot you'll have to `enable` it by running:

```
[sudo] systemctl enable myservice
```

If you don't enable it, it won't start on boot but you'll still be able to start it manually by running:

```
[sudo] systemctl start myservice
```

If a service is already enabled and you want to disable it from running on boot:

```
[sudo] systemctl disable myservice
```

Remember to run reload the systemd daemon after changing the config and enabling/disabling services:

```
[sudo] systemctl daemon-reload
```